# Push Notification not Receiving after bb10 restart in Android Runtime

Tags: android, push-notification, blackberry-10

I have converted the android app to bb10, here am able to get the push notification in bb10 until bb10 restart. If i have restart the device then the notification not receiving.If i install the app once again then able to get the notification. How can i get the notification if i restart the device also?

I have added the below permission in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />                                        
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<receiver 
            android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"    // I have changed this also com.packagename.GCMBroadcastReceiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.packagename" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" /> //I have changed this also..            <service android:name="com.packagename.GCMIntentService" />
```

Is i need to change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a BB10 dev alpha A device, the push notifications would stop working after the phone was restarted. - this may be the case on other dev alpha devices.

On production devices I think the Android runtime needs to be started (run at least one android ported app to start it up) in order for your application to actually be able to receive push notifications, however I'm not 100% on the details on this one (which is why I ended up on your question while searching).

edit:
according to some BB "documentation", you'll find that the Android runtime promises even less: "The Android Runtime will queue your pushes until the application is launched." - see https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html which is rather scarce on actual, useful details.